# C++ random question

Tags: c++, random

test

```
RandomNumberGenerator rng;
cout << rng() << endl;
```

header

```
class RandomNumberGenerator {
public:
    unsigned long operator()(); 
};
```

cpp

```
unsigned long operator()() {   // HERE IS ERROR
srand(time(NULL));
unsigned long r = rand();
return r;
}
```

basically im trying to do a random number generator. 
but getting an error :

C:\CodeBlocks\kool\praks3\src\myfunctors.cpp|5|error: 'long unsigned int operator()()' must be a nonstatic member function|

Comment: As an aside, it's probably not a good idea to re-seed the random number generator with srand(time(NULL)) every time you need a random value. Seed it once, and then generate each number in the sequence without calling srand() each time.

Comment: Other people have already answered your actual question, but here's another observation: your actual implementation is a very, very bad idea. The granularity of `time()` is only 1 second, which means that two calls to rng() within a single second are likely to get the same result. The relationship between your seed and the output of the first `rand()` after setting it is not guaranteed to be terribly complex. Someone who knows what time it is can predict the behaviour of your program. Etc., etc., etc. Don't do this. [EDITED: oops, pmjordan said much the same thing while I was writing this.]

Comment: @pmjordan @Gareth: so any other seed suggestions?

Comment: Seeding with time() is fine for applications that aren't especially security critical as long as you only do it once (or rarely). If in doubt, call srand() at the start of the program and never again. If the quality of generated random numbers is important, try the RNGs that ship with boost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler that the `operator()()` belongs in the `RandomNumberGenerator` class by using `::`:

```
unsigned long RandomNumberGenerator::operator()()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned long r = rand();
    return r;
}
```

The compiler says that it "must be a nonstatic member function" because `operator()()` is required to be a member of a class and not a global function. And without the scoping operator the compiler thinks that the `operator()()` is a global function and thus not a member of `RandomNumberGenerator`, which is the source of the error.

Don't forget to include the header for the `RandomNumberGenerator` class into the source file!

Comment: damn i keep forgetting the scope..oh me, beginner

Answer (score 3):

Outside the class, this is how you've to define the `operator()`:

```
unsigned long RandomNumberGenerator::operator()() {
  //note this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   srand(time(NULL));
   unsigned long r = rand();
   return r;
}
```

The part `RandomNumberGenerator::` tells the compiler that `operator()` belongs to the class `RandomNumberGenerator`.

Answer (score 2):

You are not scoping your operator.

Try this:

```
unsigned long RandomNumberGenerator::operator()() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    unsigned long r = rand();
    return r;
}
```

Regards,
Dennis M.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify the scope, try `unsigned long RandomNumberGenerator :: operator()()`
The point is, how should the compiler otherwise know to which class your `operator()` belongs to?